# Difference between $\sin(\arcsin(x))$ and $ \arcsin(\sin x)$

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, inverse-function

What's the difference between $\sin(\arcsin(x))$ and $ \arcsin(\sin x)$ ? I think these are equal each other and equals to $x$ . Also , what's the plot of these functions ? I'm really confused about inverse function and its concept that is appearing in many situations and problems like this.

Comment: Note the range of the arcsin function.  Not the domain as well

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148679/why-arent-the-graphs-of-sin-arcsin-x-and-arcsin-sin-x-the-same

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Can you provide several trustable sources for inverse function ?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt So , in $[-\pi/2   \  \pi/2]$ interval , two functions are same and plot is $y=x$ . Am I right ?

Comment: @S.H.W No, $\sin(\arcsin(x))$ is undefined for $|x|>1$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I'm sorry , I made a mistake. In $[-1 \  1]$ interval two functions are equal and plot of them is $y=x$. Is this right ?

Comment: Yup.  :D  I do think the question marked as duplicate is very good though.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thank you a lot , like many times that you have answered my questions.